# Escaping and unescaping a string with single and double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, escaping, html-escape-characters

I have a search box that a user can search for any string including single AND double quotes, once they have searched, the backend is passing the keyword back to me so I can put it back in the box. I don't know what the string is so I can't escape quotes myself, below is an example:

```
var keyword = "hello";
$("#selectionkeywords").val();
```

The issue I am having is that if the user enters "hello" the keyword becomes ""hello"" and I get this error:

```
missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   
jQuery("#selectionkeywords").val(""hello"");
```

The user could also enter single quotes so that rules it out as well. I tried using escape unescape but I still have the same issue e.g. escape(""hello"")
I could get the value in an unescaped format e.g. "hello" but I don't know what to do with it, escape doesn't work on it I end up with this %26%23034%3Bhello%26%23034%3B

So I'm pretty much stuck at the moment as I can't do anything to the string, any ideas?

Comment: `string.replace('""','"');` You should fix this on the serverside IMO!

Comment: can you modify what the backend is returning?

Comment: I can ask the java developer to change it but what to?

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the string server side, so javascript receives it already escaped, in the case of PHP you could do:

```
$var = str_replace('"', '\"', $var);
```

and then in javascript make sure you read it between double quotes, as you escaped for that:

```
//use double quotes, as you escaped for them
jQuery("#selectionkeywords").val("<?php echo $var ?>");
```

Comment: I can choose to receive it escaped or unescaped but neither are helpful because I can't use any sort of replace method. I'm not using php but I tried using this method mykeyword.replace('"', '\"') but what if the mykeyword contains a single quote? this will only work in one situation

Comment: If the backend is giving you `jQuery("#selectionkeywords").val(""hello"");` then there is *nothing* you can do because that is not even valid javascript. It's an empty string, the identifier `hello` and then an empty string, all smooshed together. What you want is for the backend to give you `jQuery(#selectionkeywords").val("\"hello\"");`. You can do this in PHP with `addslashes($str);` which escapes single quotes and double quotes using the backslash.

Comment: @Reina My same answer above works if the string contains single quotes, because single quotes inside double quotes are safe, and I use double quotes around the PHP `echo $var` in my code above.

Answer (score 1):

When you exchange data from server to client and viceversa, you want to use base64 encoding and decoding, in order to avoid this and other kinds of problems.

**Java side:**

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

/* ... */

/* Decode input from client */
String input = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(inputFromClient);

/* Encode output for client */
String output = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encodedOutput);
```

**Javascript side:**

```
// Encode data for the server
var dataForServer = Base64.encode(data);

// Decode data coming from the server
var data = Base64.decode(dataFromServer);
```

using this class

```
var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish I had a say in what we use

Comment: You said you could ask to the java developer, but you do not know what. Here you go.